# How can I include time spent in I/O when using GHC profiler?

Tags: haskell, ghc

When using GHC's profiler capabilities, e.g. passing `+RTS -p -RTS` options, it does not take into account time spent waiting for I/O operations. This kind of makes sense but I would be interested in profiling my application taking into account this time, as I would like to ensure this code does not introduce significant overhead (this is a test-driver application talking to our system through the network, so I expect time spent in HTTP queries to dwarf any other cost).

Is there a way to do that using GHC?

Comment: Can you share the code that's leading you to believe profile results don't take into account I/O? You may very well be right but my understanding is the monotonic clock is used for ticks. But you might also be interested in http://www.well-typed.com/blog/86/ as well as trying out `perf` with your Haskell compiled with dwarf debug symbols

Comment: As I said, this is a client tester and the profiler tells me it spends ~1.2% of its time in `runClientM` which is simply not possible. Thanks for the point, I will have a look.

Comment: (can confirm `threadDelay` and waits on a socket don't show up in cpu profile)